# How to solve "Error in rstudio_with_ansi_support()"?

Tags: r, rstudio, diffobj

I've searched for the problem on error messages on `diffPrint()` function in R.

However, I have no idea how to solve this error. When I applied to `diffPrint()`, the characters in two data were garbled; thus, I couldn't read them. Moreover, `diffPrint(`) and `diffObj()` functions didn't work.

Let me show you my codes and error messages.

```
A <- read.csv("Ex1.csv", header=T, colClasses=rep("character",5)) # In order to load '00012' and something else, I used 'colClasses=rep("character",5))
B <- read.csv("Ex2.csv", header=T, colClasses=rep("character",5))
B <- data.frame(unique(B[,c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4")])) # Removing duplicated data

# install.packages("diffobj") # In order to check differences on A and B data
library(diffObj)

diffPrint(A, B)
Press ENTER to continue...
diffObj(A, B)
```

> ```
> Error in rstudio_with_ansi_support() :
>   could not find function "rstudio_with_ansi_support"
> ```

And this is my Viewer capture, when `diffObj()` was used.

[image]

In addition, data A has 1978 observations of 5 variables; on the other hand, data B has 2008 observations of 5 variable. The variables' names are totally same.

Anybody who can help me?

Comment: I would recommend you restart your session.  There seems to be a weird incompatibility happening with `crayon`, which was recently updated.  If the error persists, please run `traceback()` right after the error, as well as `sessionInfo()`, and paste the results.  Finally, please `dput` a small set of your data (e.g. 5 rows) that reproduces the error.

Comment: I typed traceback() and then sessionInfo(), then dput(A), dput(B) were used. However, it still doesn't work.

Comment: This is my sessionInfo() result.
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
Matrix products: default
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Korean_Korea.949  LC_CTYPE=Korean_Korea.949   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Korean_Korea.949 LC_NUMERIC=C                
[5] LC_TIME=Korean_Korea.949    
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
[1] diffobj_0.1.6
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1 tools_3.4.1    crayon_1.3.2

Comment: Try updating your crayon package ("install.packages('crayon')").

Comment: Fyi, this is [filed as an issue now](https://github.com/brodieG/diffobj/issues/108), although the work-around above should work for you in the meantime.

Comment: @BrodieG Thank you so much! After installing 'crayon' packages again, the [diffObj()] function works very well. However, characters in my data were broken. I guess all alphabets are not English; thus, the all words are illegible, but I am okay. I found another package, which compares two different data like [diffObj()]. I extremely appreciate your help. :)